# Python - joining item in list with strings

Tags: python, string, list, join, character

I have looked everywhere, and can't find an answer. I am about 1-2 weeks old to Python so not very long. How can I join different items in lists with a string?

In my case, I want to show the 3D dimensions of an object: (Simplified a lot)

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
join_list = my_list[0],"x",my_list[1],"x",my_list[2]
print(join_list)
```

This returns with:

```
(1, 'x', 2, 'x', 3)
```

I am aiming to get 1x2x3 instead of (1, 'x', 2, 'x', 3). Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: do you want to end up with a string?

Comment: @RafaelBarros yes

Comment: Try this: `'x'.join(map(str, my_list))`

Comment: the str.join method concatenates everything in the list separating it by itself, in this case, 'x'. it's used with comma sometimes. Important note: you need to have a list of strings, that's why I called the `map` there, to cast all the numbers to strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple Python [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) operation. The problem that I just realized was that you have to convert the integers in the list to strings first. You can do that with a simple list comprehension like this.

```
'x'.join([str(x) for x in my_list])
```

Comment: Im so dumb thanks :p

Comment: How would I do it though if they were other characters such as x/y/z? just wondering

Comment: In your follow-up, if `x`, `y`, and `z` are all numbers like above and you just wanted `/` characters in between, you could do `'/'.join([str(x) for x in my_list])`. If `x`, `y`, and `z` are strings in `my_list`, you could just do `'/'.join(my_list)`.

Comment: That's great @George_E! Stick with it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'x'.join(str(e) for e in my_list)
```